# What kind of encryption is this? 8-4-4-4-12 characters

Tags: encryption, hash, uuid

I have got a string similar to the following

```
7bac91ba-55f1-4eaa-b480-162c98e65b6e
```

or

```
571420b3 57b5 4617 9c1e d8880f46806c
```

This could be a UUID but I am not really sure. Is there a way of decoding it?
Thanks.

Comment: It could be an ICBM sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a UUID or GUID i.e. a unique number there is no real pattern.

A long time ago it used to be common to find a MAC (network card address) but not so common nowadays.

Comment: All right, thanks. So there is no way for decoding it. I will accept your answer in some minutes.

Comment: you are assuming that something is actually encoded - there is no consistent way of creating them - e.g. in ruby they have several techniques http://uuidtools.rubyforge.org/api/ - though I have no idea why one would be used over another

Comment: Its still used in COM registration and many other applications that require a global unique identifier.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier may be of help for some sort of decoding but as I said is supposed to be random and unique(?) any fixed values that could be decoded would limit the scope and increase the chance of a collision - as I understand it.